# loop through each file using audio_tag Rails 5

Tags: ruby, loops, audio, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to RoR. I am trying to use audio_tag to reproduce files. My code is reproducing the same song on each audio_tag shown. I would like it to loop through the existed audio files and reproduce them according to its link.

All help will be appreciated!

My code so far:

```
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
    <ul>
      <%= link_to song.name, song.url %>
      <%= audio_tag(Song.pluck(:url), controls: true) %>
      ///
      <%= link_to "Delete >",  "songs/delete/?song=" + song.name, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete ' + song.name + '?' %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Song.pluck(:url)` will return an array of the `url` of every song in your database.

I think you may want:

```
<?= audio_tag(song.url, controls: true) %>
```

This will use the url for the current `song` object.